# Url rewrite not functioning in subdirectory creation runtime show blank page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on my some project.Main issue which I face is url rewriting through .htaccess
I just want to write 
`http://www.domain.com.au/servives.php?alphabet=a` to `http://www.domain.com.au/cat/alphabet/a.htm` using the rule  `RewriteRule ^cat/alphabet/([^/]+)\.htm$ /services.php?alphabet=$1 [NC,PT]`

### My Total .htaccess file contains

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Options +Indexes
RewriteBase /


//commented// This rule to resolve cononicalization

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com.au/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cat/alphabet/([^/]+)\.htm$ /services.php?alphabet=$1 [NC,PT]
```

But, this opens a blank page when I type In browser http://www.domain.com.au/cat/alphabet/a.htm
opens a blank page but it contains source code show no errors but still blank.

If I add additional parameter of [R] then it redirect to the original page external redirect work fine. I spend atleast week in it and so confused.your help is so appreciated .
it redirects with this (with additional R flag)

`RewriteRule ^cat/alphabet/([^/]+)\.htm$ /services.php?alphabet=$1 [NC,R]`

Why its not redirect internally?

Comment: hey freinds I got answer my self .. post there might be help any other :) . this issue is due to the file path which i include in my file are all distrubed because I gave all relative path not absolute path which cause this issue

Comment: <base href="/">
<base href="http://example.com/">

Comment: <base href="/">
<base href="http://example.com/">  use this in head section to resolve url from root this will fix issue